# In order to be a C++ programmer, should I always std::vector instead of making my own linked list?

Tags: c++

Right now I'm making a class called `Stopwatch` for a Windows phone app. I need a dynamic data to add *laps* like a stopwatch does. That is, if a user presses the *lap* button while the stopwatch is running, it adds a data structure

```
struct lap
{
   unsigned double start;
   unsigned double stop;
}
```

(defined as a private variable in my `Stopwatch` class) to the end of some sort of dynamic data structure that is saving all the laps.

Now, **Bjarne Stroustrup himself says that we should always use `std::vector` over linked lists**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo. So the Lord of C++ tells me that I should have

```
std::vector<Stopwatch::lap> Laps;
```

as a private variable in my class. However, at the same time, I don't need anywhere near all the functionalities of an `std::vector`, since the only things I'll be using it for is iterating through the elements and using `push_back()`. Should I create another generic linked list class that is limited to the functionalities I need?

Comment: FYI, Bjarne Stroustrup is the creator of C++

Comment: `vector` is not analogous to a linked list.

Comment: It is fun to create your first container structure... fun starts to wear out on the 2nd, the third... And BTW, a vector is not a linked list.

Comment: This is completely opinion based because both approaches work. Personally, I think you should not create a new collection class. Chances are, you will either introduce bugs, or waste a ton of time testing it. std::vector works well, why not use it. I for one would not buy an additional new car, just because my current car can do more than required.

Comment: @user3474967 Offtopic: So, Bjarne recommends vectors over lists. Ok. But you still ask if you must reimplement list. Not vector. Where is the logic? Probably, you need to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I don't think it's opinion-based; it's based on a mistaken assumption. "I don't need all those functions" implies that you'd get them. You don't; only the vector methods used are instantiated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need a linked-list, you can use `std::list`. But linked lists are rarely the correct tool. Way overstressed in programming books and courses, in my opinion. The default choice for a dynamically resizable sequence container in C++ is `std::vector`. So use it. If you don't need the extra functionality, don't use it (the unneeded functionality). It costs you nothing. Don't waste your time implementing another redundant and buggy sequence container.

Comment: Further, vectors are optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Not needing all the available functionality provided by a standard class is a poor reason to write your own. If everyone followed that logic, we'd have tonnes of non-standard classes which just provide subsets of the functionality of the standard classes.

Moreover, it is not trivial to write classes representing abstract data structures, and your own implementations are more likely to have bugs than the standard one, and will likely not be as optimised.

Finally, it is not a significant drain of resources to use classes which provide more functionality than you use. This functionality is primarily just method implementations, and they don't take up a lot of space in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 0):

The std algorithms and containers use an efficient code base that is reusable and extensible. You should consider that other programmers should be able to understand your code simply and reuse or extend it. It is much more better to use std containers for regular usage. That's because most programmers are familiar with std and also most of the algorithms in std are very optimized and i doubt you can write something faster that std::sort.

Unless when performance demands are critical, or the container requirements are very specific, there may be no choice but to implement a container from scratch.